# Location of calls to SQL SP in controller

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Newbie here again. I've got a controller in C# that I need to place a call to SQL in, somewhere. So far, I seem to be lacking in formatting skills.

```
namespace invoiceViewer.Controllers
{
    public class invoiceController : ApiController
    {
        <Area one>

    }
<area two>
}
```

Should my call to SP go in area one or two? If two, do I do away with that class?

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question, I've been learning C# for all of a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you propose placing the code inside of the class definition which would not work.

Most patterns have some kind of data access layer which is used to make calls to the database and update/get data from it. For example:

```
namespace invoiceViewer.DAL
{
    public static class InvoiceDAL
    {
        public static foo GetFooData()
        {
            //DB access code goes here
            //Get data
            //return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your class:

```
namespace invoiceViewer.Controllers
{
    public class invoiceController : ApiController
    {
        public invoiceController() {}

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            foo data = InvoiceDAL.GetFooData();
        }
    }
}
```

If you've been learning C# for a week I would recommend stopping what your doing with this project and to learn a bit more first. Once you have a grasp of the basics, check out some of the [MVC tutorials on the asp.net site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) to get started. Entity framework makes working with databases a breeze.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Assuming I'm using the default layout of VS, would it be a good idea to put the DAL in app_data?

Comment: In light of that, I've just discovered the class library. Is this where you are referring to?

Comment: No, the `App_Data` is a special folder and is used for file based storage instead of a DB. I'd recommend a `DAL` folder or something in the root or the site.